# create an ip alias for a sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

We have a sidecar running an API at localhost:myportnumber (lets say 8888 for this example), and we are trying to reference it from the main container in the same pod.

Does the main container need to be aware of the port the sidecar is running on? (like by creating an environment variable equal to 8888?)

Or is there a convenient way we can reference the sidecar using something similar to cluster ip (like namespace.servicename.sidecarname), or by creating a [HostAlias](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/)?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF].

Comment: The *address* of something (obtained from a hostname, alias, etc) has nothing to do with the port number on which a service is running. You will always need to specify a port number (unless you're using a service like http or https which has a common default if nothing is provided explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the main container need to be aware of the port the sidecar is running on? (like by creating an environment variable equal to 8888?)

> Yes , sidecar containers share same network(IP,namespace) so you have to make main container aware of the port number on which it can reach the sidecar container.

is there a convenient way we can reference the sidecar using something similar to cluster ip (like namespace.servicename.sidecarname), or by creating a HostAlias?

> I think DNS/similar things cannot be extended to containers that are running inside pods . because as mentioned above all the contianers inside a pod share same nework(IP , Network namespace)